# Java For-Each Loop : Sort order

Tags: java, syntax, loops

Does a java for-each loop guarantee that the elements will be presented in order if invoked on a list? In my tests it does seem to, but I can't seem to find this explicitly mentioned in any documentation

```
List<Integer> myList;// [1,2,3,4]
for (Integer i : myList) {
  System.out.println(i.intValue());
}

#output
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes.  The foreach loop will iterate through the list in the order provided by the `iterator()` method.  See the [documentation for the Iterable interface](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

If you look at the [Javadoc for List](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) you can see that a list is an "ordered collection" and that the `iterator()` method returns an iterator that iterates "in proper sequence".

Answer (score 15):

The `foreach` loop will use the iterator built into the `Collection`, so the order you get results in will depend whether or not the `Collection` maintains some kind of order to the elements.

So, if you're looping over an `ArrayList`, you'll get items in the order they were inserted (assuming you didn't go on to sort the ArrayList). If you're looping over a `HashSet`, all bets are off, since HashSets don't maintain any ordering.

If you need to guarantee an order to the elements in the Collection, define a `Comparator` that establishes that order and use `Collections.sort(Collection<T>, Comparator<? super T>)`.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the Java language specs ensure that

```
for (Iterator<Whatever> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
    whatEver(i.next());
```

is equivalent to

```
for (Whatever x : c)
    whatEver(x);
```

no "change in ordering" is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a for loop, a la `for (int i = 0; i < myList.length(); i++)` if you want to do it in an ordered manner. Though, as far as I know, foreach should do it in order.

Comment: yeah but that's really ugly, i'd rather be certain about for-each