# How does .net determine the order for the "foreach" loop?

Tags: .net, collections, foreach

When I use the `foreach` statement in C# .net, how does .net determine in what order to process the elements in the collection?

Comment: What type of collection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort order of C# for each loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790245/sort-order-of-c-for-each-loop)

Comment: Thanks for the asnwers!  I'm going to have to learn about the IEnumerable interface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `foreach`, the object which implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` is "iterated".  The order is determined by the object's implementation of `IEnumerable`.

Any class can customize the order in which this occurs.  With a `List<T>`, for example, it's in the list's order (by index).  However, some classes such as `Dictionary<T,U>` do not guarantee an order at all - only that each item will get enumerated through one time, as providing an ordering guarantee in that case would dramatically hamper performance.

Comment: I like the answer that was deleted "I'm pretty sure it just starts at 0 and goes until there isn't any more."

Answer (score 1):

It's using the IEnumerable and IEnumerator interfaces. They a providing the values one after another, so .Net does not have to care about ordering. It's processing the values just in the order as they are delivered.