# C# foreach iterator isn't traversing my List in order

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I was wondering if someone could explain why the list doesn't print out in order in the foreach loop? I also noticed that the .ToList() changes the order of the cards if you look at them in the watch window. Why would that be?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CardShuffle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var r = new Random();
            var cards = Enumerable.Range(0, 51);
            var shuffledcards = cards.OrderBy(a => r.Next(1000));
            var aList = shuffledcards.ToList();

            foreach( int card in aList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Card {0} is {1}.", card, aList[card]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int card = 0; card < aList.Count; ++card )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Card {0} is {1}.", card, aList[card]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the order you want? your list should have a random order.

Comment: you're ordering based on a random number

Comment: @KingKing I think it should be random as he's just "shuffled" the cards with `var shuffledcards = cards.OrderBy(a => r.Next(1000));`

Comment: His issue is that the for loop and the foreach produce different printouts. This has been asked and answered multiple times... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790245/sort-order-of-c-sharp-for-each-loop

Comment: as for your second question, probably because of the lazy evaluation of LINQ.

Comment: Your foreach loop is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bug in your foreach;

```
foreach( int card in aList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Card {0} is {1}.", card, aList[card]);
}
```

`card` is not the index, it's the value itself. So you're printing the value (as the card number) then randomly accessing whatever is at that index and displaying it as the value. You should be using a counter to display the card number and using `card` to replace `{1}`.

```
int i = 0;
foreach( int card in aList)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Card {0} is {1}.", i, card);
     i++;
}
```

Comment: I think in fact the `card` here is one of the indices of `aList`, because the source list uses `Enumerable.Range(0,51)`

Comment: @KingKing Those integers are just the data of the list; they don't appear to actually be intended to be indexes to anything.

Comment: @Servy it should not be used that way, but it is legal and runs OK. Do you mean it would throw some exception? I just talked about the values, the source list of the OP means that value at index `i` will have value `i`. That means `list[list[i]] = i`

Comment: @KingKing The source of the OP's confusing is that he choose to use a list of ints to test out shuffling, and he's confusing himself between whether he has an index to the item or the item itself, because both the index and the value is an `int`.  If the values were, say, strings, it would result in compile time errors.  As it is, it just results in non-nonsensical code.  Since the items are, more or less, shuffled, looking up the item at the index of any given value is more or less a random item, which is why it looks like a different random ordering.

Comment: @Servy I don't even care about he's doing. He even didn't talk what's he trying to do. The first of course can't be used for testing. BTW, to test it we don't even need to print the indices. Printing the values is enough. Because the source list has values 0,1,2,3... The values after being shuffled OK would have a different order. That's why I didn't understand what he was trying to do.

Comment: Yeah @Servy's last post is accurate. The OP is thinking the list is printed in a different order because of a couple of coincidences. Like Servy said if the collection had strings for the card names rather than ints it would cause compile time errors. If the values in the collection weren't 0-51 then he would get IndexOutOfRange exceptions at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have

```
List<int> aList = new List<int>();
aList.Add(1);
aList.Add(5);
aList.Add(10);
aList.Add(20);
```

and you are trying to do

```
foreach( int card in aList)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Card {0} is {1}.", card, aList[card]);
   }
```

What you are actually doing is trying to access random elements of array, because in the second loop in my case  it will access the fifth element of array not the second one, so you need to run for loop if you want the correct result.

Comment: There's no such thing as `new List {...}` in C#. Please correct your code.

Comment: yeap... sorry, just did

Comment: @HighCore to me it looks like pseudo code for static initialization of `List<T>`, ofc it wouldn't compile, but idk where he's going with it. My answer has the cause of the problem :)

Comment: @Stanislav just wanna point out you could have `List<int> aList = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 10, 20 };` and it would compile and run.

Comment: Actually my answer has explanation of the problem based on simple pseudo example :)

Comment: I haven't tried it :) but hopefully the guy who asked the question got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

In the foreach loop you're writing the cards using the values as the index. In the for loop your writing the cards in order based on index.

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` loop logic is wrong. What you're doing there is you're taking items from `aList` collection, and then use them as an index to take another element in `aList` collection. That's why you get that kind of output.

To get the same output from your `foreach` as from your `for` loop, try that:

```
foreach (var item in aList.Select((c, i) => new { card = c, index = i }))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Card {0} is {1}.", item.index, item.card);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop is incorrect. Try this

```
int counter = 0;
foreach( int card in aList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Card {0} is {1}", counter , card);
    counter++;
}
```