# Unexpected behaviour with LINQ to Entities, possible bug?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

**Background**
I log searches in my application and want to present the ratio between the different types of searches in an statistics view.

**Issue**
I wanted to keep is as efficient and condensed as possible in LINQ but still keep it clear considering the limitations of what you can use in a LINQ query, so my attempt was this:

(Please disregard the fact that I'm not using a separate entity for the search types, this has it's reasons)

```
    var result = MyEntities.Instance.SearchStatistics
        .GroupBy(x => x.SearchType)
        .Select(y => new List<string> { { y.Key }, { SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)y.Count()).Trim() } })
        .ToList();

    return Json(new
    {
        Text = result.First(x => x.ElementAt(0) == "Text").ElementAt(1),
        Organization = result.First(x => x.ElementAt(0) == "Organization").ElementAt(1),
        Subject = result.First(x => x.ElementAt(0) == "Subject").ElementAt(1),
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This behaved in an unexpected way though, the resulting List in the list of lists got it's values in every other row flipped.

I expected **{{"Text", "123"}, {"Organization", "123"}, {"Subject", "123"},...}**
but instead got **{{"Text", "123"}, {"123", "Organization"}, {"Subject", "123"},...}**

I did not understand why, and tried to partition the query

```
    var preresult = MyEntities.Instance.SearchStatistics
        .GroupBy(x => x.SearchType).ToList();

    var result = preresult
        .Select(y => new List<string> { { y.Key }, { y.Count().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) } }).ToList();
```

And now it worked as expected when only the grouping query was executed in the DB

Logging the resulting sql of the LINQ query to the DB, I got this result for the "faulty" one:

```
SELECT [Project3].[SearchType] AS [SearchType],
       [Project3].[C2]         AS [C1],
       [Project3].[C1]         AS [C2]
FROM   (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C1] = 0) THEN [GroupBy1].[K1]
                 ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(CAST([GroupBy1].[A1] AS decimal(19, 0)))))
               END             AS [C1],
               [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [SearchType],
               1               AS [C2]
        FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[SearchType] AS [K1],
                       COUNT(1)               AS [A1]
                FROM   [app].[SearchStatistic] AS [Extent1]
                GROUP  BY [Extent1].[SearchType]) AS [GroupBy1]
               CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS [C1]
                           FROM   (SELECT 1 AS X) AS [SingleRowTable1]
                           UNION ALL


                           SELECT 1 AS [C1]
                           FROM   (SELECT 1 AS X) AS [SingleRowTable2]) AS [UnionAll1]) AS [Project3]
ORDER  BY [Project3].[SearchType] ASC,
          [Project3].[C2] ASC
```

Unfortunately I have limited experience in SQL and my head hurts just by looking at that, but something is obviously getting mixed up.

Can someone pinpoint where the problem in the sql query lies?

Is it reasonable that I would expect this as I want to? Could it be considered a bug, or is it just my expectations that have no support in the contract of how LINQ should work?

**Update**

Hold on, why did I not look at the output from the SQL query directly? The mind works in mysterious ways...

The sql query is returning this :

```
[SearchType, C1, C2]
{Text, 1, Text}  
{Text, 1, 123}  
{Organization, 1, 123}  
{Organization, 1, Organization}  
{Subject, 1, Subject}  
{Subject, 1, 123}
```

But the result after .ToList() is still only containing three items. This is only making me more confused, surely must be some implicit internal behavior of LINQ that have unintended consequences?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to believe that the order of name and value is flipped in the JSON object, but apparently it happens.

It may have to do with the fact that the order of items in a `List<T>` is never guaranteed to be equal to the insertion order. You can prevent this issue by not using a list at all:

```
var result = MyEntities.Instance.SearchStatistics
    .GroupBy(x => x.SearchType)
    .Select(y => new { y.Key, Count = y.Count() })
    .ToList();

return Json(new
{
    Text = result.First(x => x.Key == "Text").Count.ToString(),
    Organization = result.First(x => Key) == "Organization").Count.ToString(),
    Subject = result.First(x => x.Key == "Subject").Count.ToString(),
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution but, "It may have to do with the fact that the order of items in a List<T> is never guaranteed to be equal to the insertion order." Isn't that just what it is? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043039/does-listt-guarantee-insertion-order

Comment: I guess you're right, although it's not documented (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1790265/861716). But yeah if not, what would be the point of a `Sort` method? But I can't really explain what's happening in your code.

Comment: But seeing your update, I think I would still go for a solution which keeps the database query simple and do conversion in memory. EF tries to translate *everything* in the LINQ expression into SQL, so the conversions and the creation of the list cause a lot of clutter. Also, the SQL result set doesn't always reflect the final result of the EF query, because EF may filter results in its post processing (still doesn't explain anything though, but at least the SQL will be cleaner so it's easier to check it).

Comment: Yes, I will definitely use your solution with the anonymous type instead, much cleaner, the generated SQL is much simpler, and it actually produces what you expected. Still interesting to know the reason for the this issue...