# Does For Each on List return items in order of addition?

Tags: vb.net, list, foreach, vb.net-2010

If I add items to a `List(Of T)` and then use a `For Each` to iterate over them, are they guaranteed to visited in the same order they were added?

Or for that matter, are they added at indexes related to the adding order? (i.e. is the first added object at index 0, the second at index 1, etc)

e.g: Will the below code be guaranteed to to print the output "0 1 2" from both loops?

```
Private MyList As New List(Of Integer)
MyList.Add(New Integer(0))
MyList.Add(New Integer(1))
MyList.Add(New Integer(2))

For Each n As Integer In MyList
    Console.Write(n.ToString & " ")
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To MyList.Count - 1
    Console.Write(MyList(i).ToString & " ")
Next
```

**EDIT**: Thanks for pointing out that the first part of this question is answered by [In what order does a C# for each loop iterate over a List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790245/in-what-order-does-a-c-sharp-for-each-loop-iterate-over-a-listt)

However the second part qualifies the question a little further. The linked question states that yes, the `For Each` iterates from index `0` to index `count - 1`. But does the .Add() method always add at the next unused highest index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In what order does a C# for each loop iterate over a List<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790245/in-what-order-does-a-c-sharp-for-each-loop-iterate-over-a-listt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every added element to a List gets a higher index. So first is always 0, second 1 etc.
Foreach will always loop the list from the beginning to the end. If you like to do it from the end, you can for example use FOR loop for that or you can sort the list the way you like (f.e. LINQ).

The easiest way to verify this is simply debuging your code.
Using provided code by you (little edits were made):

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim MyList As New List(Of Integer)
    MyList.Add(0)
    MyList.Add(1)
    MyList.Add(2)

    For Each n As Integer In MyList
        Console.Write(n.ToString & " ")
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To MyList.Count - 1
        Console.Write(MyList(i).ToString & " ")
    Next

    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

The output will be:

```
0 1 2 0 1 2
```

If you'd like to insert an element somewhere in the middle, you can use:

```
MyList.Insert(position, value)
```

Comment: Keran, Is there documentation reference for this? The MSDN pages I had been reading skew off into talking about sorting, rather than mentioning any specifics on ordering.

Comment: Yup, here it is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx
"The object to be added to the **end** of the List<T>"

Comment: Ta, missed that small bit!